# Adding CSS @keyframes animation to state change in React app

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router, flux

I have a React + Flux application with `react-router` for routing. There's a `.button` component whith `.button_active` CSS class toggled to it in React's `onClick` event as well as the `toggled:true` state is being added to the button object on top of the app via a Flux Action.

So the `.button_active` class has CSS `@keyframes` animation attached to it to animate the state change of the `.button` from regular to active and vice versa.

Everything works well except that the animation is fired not only on click (state change), but also on every route change (the `.button_active` className is in place, but the parent div is being created/destroyed each time the route changes so the animation keeps on firing).

Is there a way to avoid such behavior but still use the @keyframes animation to animate the state changes?

Thanks!

Comment: React does not normally destroy/recreate the elements on every route change.  You've got something else going on.  It sounds like you are manually manipulating the DOM in your onClick event, which can cause problems.  Please show some code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to remove the `.button_active` in `componentWillUnmount()`, maybe this will work.